# Creating "running total" in Scala

Tags: scala, cumulative-sum

I have a history `DataFrame` that has the following structure

```
id      amount  date

12345   150     1/1/2016

12345   50      1/4/2016

12345   250     1/4/2016

12345   950     1/9/2016
```

I would like to have a cumulative sum of $ with respect to date, such that the resulting sum is calculated as the sum of all earlier days with the same ID. results should be generated even for dates that do not have entries in the source DataFrame, assuming they are between the start and end dates. The expected output for the example input can be seen below.

```
ID      date        cumulative_sum

12345   1/1/2016    150

12345   1/2/2016    150

12345   1/3/2016    150

12345   1/4/2016    450

12345   1/5/2016    450

12345   1/6/2016    450

12345   1/7/2016    450

12345   1/8/2016    450

12346   1/9/2016    1400
```

Does anyone know how to calculate this sort of running total?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you first find subtotals for each date (doesn't really have to happen as a separate step, but this makes things a little more generic - I'll explain why below):

```
val subtotals = data
  .groupBy(_.date)
  .mapValues(_.map(_.amount).sum)
  .withDefault(_ => 0)
```

Now, you can scan through the date range, and sum things up with something like this:

```
(0 to numberOfMonths)
  .map(startDate.plusMonths)
  .scanLeft(null -> 0) { case ((_, sum), date) => 
     date -> (subtotals(date) + sum)
  }.drop(1)
```

This is how you would do this is in "plain scala". Now, because you have mentioned "data frame", in your question, I suspect, you are actually using spark. This makes it a little bit more complicated, because the data may be distributed. The good news is, while you may have a huge number of transaction, there aren't enough months in the history of the world to make it impossible for you to process the aggregated data as a single task. 
So, you just need to replace the first step above with a distributed equivalent:

```
val subtotals = dataFrame
  .rdd
  .map(tx => tx.date -> tx.amount)
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .collect
  .toMap
```

And now you can to the second step in exactly the same way I showed above.